# How to read available input without blocking on Windows

Tags: c, windows, input, nonblocking

On Linux, I can read available input without blocking the process:

```
fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK )
char buf[n];
int r = fread(buf, 1, n, stdin);
if (r == 0){
    printf("nothing\n");
}
else {
    printf("read: ");
    fwrite(buf, 1, r, stdout);
    printf("\n");
}
```

The input origin can be anything, such as a file, a terminal or a pipe.

How can I do it on Windows XP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not read the input from a second thread?  Depending on your situation, it might be a much easier approach, instead of using non-blocking IO's.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on Windows by passing `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` to [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). It doesn't quite look the same as Linux and there may be some slight differences but it achieves the same thing.

Take a look at the MSDN page on [Synchronous vs. Asynchronous IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which provides you with even more detail on the various options.